# How to search specifically for geolocated tweets on Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, jupyter-notebook, classification, tweepy

I'm trying to search specifically for Geolocated tweets only and I can't seem to get how to do so using Tweepy in Python, any pointers?

I tried the Tweepy Cursor and Geo functions but they didn't work.